# Elasticsearch, Nest - Automap with Enabled=false creates .Chars and .Length fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I use Nest Client for creating mapping and indexing data to Elasticsearch. I am facing now a problem which I don't understand how it comes.

I use `AutoMap()` for mapping the object structure to index

```
var esClient = _esClientProvider.GetClient();
var response = esClient.Indices.Create(index,
        index => index
        .Settings(s => s.Setting("index.mapping.total_fields.limit", 2000))
        .Map<EsProduct>(
            x => x.AutoMap()
        ));
```

If I don't use `Enabled=false` annotation in the class

```
public string AssetType { get; set; }
```

There will be 2 fields generated in the index (one with text and one with keyword)

[Keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mEjg.png)

**I would like to remove the .keyword field so I use Enabled=false annotation**

```
[Object(Enabled = false)]
public string AssetType { get; set; }
```

Then now there will be 2 other fields generated in the index (one with keyword and one with integer) and with different name.

[Chars and Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSQSO.png)

I don't get the point now. I just want to skip ".keyword" field and keep the text field. Is Enabled=false not the correct solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found out how to skip the .keyword Field. I have to explicitly set the data type in the property


[Text]
public string AssetType { get; set; }